# How do I run PowerShell 4.0 after upgrading from PowerShell 2.0?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0, chocolatey

I have installed DotNet 4.5.2 and PowerShell 4 on my Windows 7 SP 1 workstation using chocolatey:

```
choco install dotnet4.5.2 -y
choco install powershell -y
```

They installed without errors and appear in the `choco list`:

```
choco list --local-only

DotNet4.5.2 4.5.2.20140902
PowerShell 4.0.20141001
```

I previously had PowerShell 2.0 installed, and when restarting PowerShell, the $host.version still shows `Major: 2`. In addition, it appears that PowerShell 4.0 only exists in the `\Program Files (x86)` not in `\Windows`, and when I list the contents of the `3.0` directory, only assemblies (no executables) are listed.

```
> dir 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell'
3.0
v1.0

> dir 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell'
v1.0

> dir 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell'
v1.0
```

Where does the PowerShell 4.0 executable live? How can I run PowerShell 4.0 instead of 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to **restart my computer** for windows update to install Microsoft Windows Management Framework 4.0

[image: Windows Update KB2819745]

Comment: Oh, that's pretty hairy. I wonder if Chocolatey could notify you when an installer has either recommended or required a restart to take effect.

Comment: If you look at the output from doing choco install powershell, you will see that the package author does tell you about this problem, and suggests that you reboot your machine.  You can see this in the chocolateyInstall.ps1 file here: https://chocolatey.org/packages/PowerShell in the Show Files section.  It not "ideal" but the information is there.